# R bootstrapping resampling with multiple observations per id and return the resample data as result

Tags: r, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a bootstrap for my data. My data (df) has the following shape.

```
id    v1    v2
1    1    1
1    0    1
1    0    1
2    2    0
2    1    1
2    0    0
```

As far as I understand, when initializing the bootstrap in R, the resampling (with reoplacement) is done on the row level, right?

so setting up sth. like:

```
boot_function <- function(data, i)
{boot_data <- data[i,]}
```

However, my first question is, how would I set this up in a scenario where I have several observations per id that need to be kept together in the bootstrap? So in my example, when doing a bootstrap, I can't simply sample among rows, but I need to sample among ids. So instead of the above

I used this one:

```
boot_function2 <- function(data, i)
{boot_data <- data[data$id %in% i,]}
```

Would that be the correct way?

And related to the above scenario I wanted to check if my approach is right, so I thought I just check how the resamples look like, but I've no idea how I can return the single bootstrap sample data frames. Any idea? (and I know, if my original data is large and I'm doing like 2000 replicates, the return object could be quite large, so i'll probably just want to spotcheck this with R=10 or so).

Comment: Seems you've got a lot ahead of you. Beware, that if you replicate with replacement, the id cluster might be drawn more than one time, and, thus, would create clusters a multiple of the intended size. Hence you should include a renaming procedure into your function. Have fun!

Comment: Technically right, but in my real bootstrap it won't be an issue. The model I'm calculating just takes the observations by going through the data row-wise. So it the example above it will take the first three observations and treat it as one id, then the next three observations and treat it as the next id and so on. Of course, this requires that no resorting of any kind is done to the data (which I can ensure).

Comment: Seems you question is more about stat methodology than code. I suggest moving  it to  [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) were you should get more and better answers.

Comment: Not really. I'm not asking sth. about the statistical backgrounds, just what the function does in the background in the resampling, i.e. if my indexing with "i" is correct and how to return the resample data sets from the bootstrap

Comment: Check out <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58504/bootstrapping-clusters-in-r> this is your question and corresponding code for clustering bootstrapping.

Comment: @MDEWITT Thanks for providing the link. However, it's a different question. This other questions deals with how to calculate statistics for each cluster separately (e.g. getting the mean for each of my ids). However, I don't want to do that. I just need to keep respective ids together in the resample, but still run models across the whole resampled data set, not individually per cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach. I will first generate some fake data:

```
ids <- rep(1:3, times = 10)
values <- rnorm(30)

dat <- data.frame(ids, values)
```

Now that we have data, we can generate the cluster bootstrapping function. This will sample from within each cluster and return a new dataframe. Then you can apply your test statistic:

```
library(tidyverse)

cluster_boot_function <- function(x){

  clusted_boot <- dat %>% 
    group_by(ids) %>% 
    nest() %>%
    mutate(samps = map(data, ~sample(.$values, size = 5, replace = T))) %>% 
    select(ids, samps) %>% 
    unnest(cols = samps)


  results <- clusted_boot %>% 
    group_by(ids) %>% 
    summarise(mu = mean(values))

  results
}
```

Now you just need to apply it repeatedly (also note that the "x" in the function doesn't do anything, I just need it there for the next step).

Here I use the `map_dfr` to return my summary statistics for each iteration:

```
out <- map_df(1:100, cluster_boot_function, .id = "iteration")
```

And this will give you your statistics for each iteration of the bootstrap:

```
# A tibble: 300 x 3
   iteration   ids    mu
   <chr>     <int> <dbl>
 1 1             1 0.150
 2 1             2 0.150
 3 1             3 0.150
 4 2             1 0.150
 5 2             2 0.150
 6 2             3 0.150
 7 3             1 0.150
 8 3             2 0.150
```

From this you could extend it to whatever kind of modeling you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the clustered sampling. However, I think it is sth. different from what I want to achieve. What you are proposing is to sample from EACH id. And within each ID you'll draw a sample. However, what I want to do is to sample among ids, but keep all rows that belong to the id. So in your example we have 3 ids. If I do a sample from my 3 ids (let's use n=1 for now) and the sample would select id 2, I want to keep all 10 rows for id=2.

Comment: I need to think about it. Maybe I can take it from here with your code and sample among the grouped ids. I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

I think bootstrapping by sample ID is absolutely fine. Here's an example using the `boot` package. I'm not sure if I understood exactly what you're bootstrapping so the function may not be exactly right, but you should be able to understand more or less what it's doing. It's not very efficient; I haven't optimised it at all given that I'm not sure about the statistic.

```r
library("boot")
ids <- rep(1:3, times = 1000)
values <- rnorm(300)

dat <- data.frame(ids, values)

boot_fun <- function(ids, i) {
  sapply(ids[i], function(j) mean(dat[dat$ids == j, "values"]))
}


boot_res <- boot(
  dat$ids,
  statistic = boot_fun,
  R = 100
)
hist(boot_res$t)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>